# Set a variable on a FormulaR1C1

Tags: excel, vba, excel-r1c1-notation

I'm trying to code a variable R1C1 formula but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I searched a lot but couldn't find any answer applicable to my case.

```
Sub Step17()
Dim Final As Integer

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[4]C:R[&Final&]C)"

End Sub
```

I created the variable "Final" because what I need to do is a sum of a range where the last row is going to be different every time so it goes from row 4 to row 50 in the first batch but in the following batch it might end up in row 200.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: `"=SUM(R[4]C:R[" & Final & "]C)"`

Comment: That everything I needed! thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @ScottCraner Please add this as an answer so it can be accepted and this question doesn't come up as unanswered.